# adding date intervals using case statement mysql

Tags: mysql, date, case

I have a table called purchase_hs. In that table i have some level dates.

```
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------+
    | level1     | level2     | level3     | level4     | level5     | transport_mode |
    +------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------+
    | 2015-02-15 | 15.02.2015 | 21.02.2015 | 19.03.2015 | 16.03.2015 | SEA            |
    | 2015-02-17 | 17.02.2015 | 17.02.2015 |            | 16.03.2015 | AIR            |
    | 2015-02-17 | 17.02.2015 | 17.02.2015 |            | 16.03.2015 | AIR            |
    | 2015-02-17 | 17.02.2015 | 17.02.2015 |            | 16.03.2015 | AIR            |
    +------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------+
```

Now based on the transport mode i need to add some days to the level dates.If transport mode = 'SEA' need to add 28 days to level1,level2 and level3, and if transport_mode = 'AIR' i need to add 14 days to level1,level2 and level3 and remaining level4 and level5 remains same while displaying.
I am trying to fetch that by using the below query. But it is not working for me.

```
SELECT level1,level2,level3,level4,level5,transport_mode,
CASE WHEN transport_mode = 'SEA'
THEN
DATE_ADD(level1, INTERVAL 28 DAY) level1, DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level2, '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 28 DAY) level2, 
DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level3, '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 28 DAY) level3
ELSE
transport_mode = 'AIR'
THEN 
DATE_ADD(level1, INTERVAL 14 DAY) level1, DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level2, '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 14 DAY) level2, 
DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level3, '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 14 DAY) level3
END 
FROM purchase_hs
```

My desierd out put will be

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------+
| level1     | level2     | level3     | level4     | level5     | transport_mode |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------+
| 2015-03-15 | 15.03.2015 | 2015-03-18 | 19.03.2015 | 16.03.2015 | SEA            |
| 2015-03-04 | 04.03.2015 | 04.03.2015 |            | 16.03.2015 | AIR            |
| 2015-03-04 | 04.03.2015 | 04.03.2015 |            | 16.03.2015 | AIR            |
| 2015-03-04 | 04.03.2015 | 04.03.2015 |            | 16.03.2015 | AIR            |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------+
```

So how can i achieve this out put? Please suggest me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a separate `CASE` expression for each column, you can't have multiple columns in a `THEN` clause. Also, you can't put a condition in the `ELSE` clause, it automatically handles all the conditions not matched by any of the `WHEN` clauses.

```
SELECT level1,level2,level3,level4,level5,transport_mode,
    CASE WHEN transport_mode = 'SEA'
        THEN DATE_ADD(level1, INTERVAL 28 DAY)
        ELSE DATE_ADD(level1, INTERVAL 14 DAY)
    END level1,
    CASE WHEN transport_mode = 'SEA'
        THEN DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level2, '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 28 DAY)
        ELSE DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level2, '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
    END level2,
    CASE WHEN transport_mode = 'SEA'
        THEN DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level3, '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 28 DAY)
        ELSE DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level3, '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 24 DAY)
    END level3
FROM purchase_hs
```

You could avoid all that repetition by using a subquery:

```
SELECT level1,level2,level3,level4,level5,transport_mode,
    DATE_ADD(level1, INTERVAL inter DAY) level1,
    DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level2, '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL inter DAY) level2,
    DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level3, '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL inter DAY) level3
FROM (SELECT level1,level2,level3,level4,level5,transport_mode,
            CASE transport_mode
                 WHEN 'SEA' THEN 28
                 WHEN 'AIR' THEN 14
                 WHEN 'PIGEON' THEN 60
                 ELSE 90
            END inter
      FROM purchase_hs) x
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , This works for me, but if i have more than 2 transport modes then how can i mention case statement?

Comment: You can have multiple `WHEN` clauses.

Comment: `CASE transport_mode WHEN 'SEA' then 28 WHEN 'AIR' THEN 14 WHEN 'CARRIER_PIGEON' THEN 60 ELSE 90 END`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a template table physical/temporary and simply join the two table as below

Your data

```
DECLARE @data AS TABLE(
level1 DATE,
level2 DATE,
level3 DATE,
level4 DATE,
level5 DATE,
mode VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @data VALUES('2015-02-15','2015-02-15','2015-02-21','2015-03-19','2015-03-16','SEA')
INSERT INTO @data VALUES('2015-02-17','2015-02-17','2015-02-17',null,'2015-03-16','AIR')
INSERT INTO @data VALUES('2015-02-17','2015-02-17','2015-02-17',null,'2015-03-16','AIR')    
INSERT INTO @data VALUES('2015-02-17','2015-02-17','2015-02-17',null,'2015-03-16','AIR')
```

Temporary template as per your logic

```
DECLARE @template AS TABLE(
level1 INT,
level2 INT,
level3 INT,
level4 INT,
level5 INT,
mode VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @template VALUES(28,28,28,0,0,'SEA')
INSERT INTO @template VALUES(14,14,14,0,0,'AIR')
```

Simply join the above two table

```
SELECT * FROM @data
SELECT * FROM @template

SELECT DATEADD(DAY,B.level1,A.level1) AS level1, 
DATEADD(DAY,B.level2,A.level2) AS level2, 
DATEADD(DAY,B.level3,A.level3) AS level3, 
DATEADD(DAY,B.level4,A.level4) AS level4, 
DATEADD(DAY,B.level5,A.level5) AS level5, 
A.mode FROM @data A INNER JOIN @template B ON A.mode = B.mode
```